# Solving for Generating Functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Suppose the EGF of $\{c_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is $(e^x - 1)^3$. Find a formula for $c_n$.

Comment: Foil (multiply out) then expand each summand $\pm \square e^{nx}$ ($0\le n\le 3$) using the series expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: Try to show that you have put some effort into it yourself. That way, people will be more willing to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

Write out

$$(e^x-1)^3 = e^{3 x} - 3 e^{2 x} + 3 e^x -1$$

which has a series expansion

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} [3^n - 3\cdot 2^n + 3 - \delta_{0n}]$$

Then

$$c_n = 3^n - 3\cdot 2^n + 3 - \delta_{0n}$$